# Can I manually generate Typescript using Fable to write the AST?

Tags: typescript, abstract-syntax-tree, typescript-compiler-api, fable-f#

I'm interested in manually generating Typescript or Javascript using Fable. One thing I'm not sure about is if it's able to provide the primitives for manaully creating the AST, such like the [typescript compiler api](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API). Does Fable have anything equivalent?

Comment: Do you mean compiling F# code to TypeScript or writing TypeScript programmatically from F#?

Comment: @sdgfsdh The latter, writing TS programmatically from F#